# SQL: Ошибка синтаксиса при выборке и суммировании значений. Через PMA все работает

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

Мой запрос. **Он работает хорошо, при использовании в PHPMyAdmin.**

```
SET @total_tokens := 0;
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  `sb_articles`.*, (@total_tokens := @total_tokens + `sb_articles`.`title_tokens`) AS `cumulative_tokens`
    FROM `sb_articles`
    WHERE `business_id` = 92
    ORDER BY id
) AS `ranked_articles`
WHERE `cumulative_tokens` >= 0 AND `cumulative_tokens` <= 4096;
```

При выполнении запроса через PHP mysqli я получаю ошибку:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  `sb_articles`.*, (@total_tokens := @total_tokens + `' at line 3 in /include/functions.php:164
Stack trace:
#0 /include/functions.php(164): mysqli->query('SET @total_toke...')
```

Где может быть ошибка?

Comment: Наверное потому что в одном `$mysql->query()` Вы пытаетесь выполнить сразу два запроса.

Comment: `from sb_articles, (select @total_tokens := 0) as x` как-то так

Comment: А ещё - переместить отбор в HAVING, и не нужен подзапрос..

Comment: @Simon спасибо, это помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Решение: Через `$mysql->query()` можно выполнить только один запрос. Нужно сначала выполнить первый, затем второй.